# JOIN AND CASE MORE AN TABLE

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables; the first one `ORG` contains the following columns:

```
ORG_REF, ARB_REF, NAME, LEVEL, START_DATE
```

and the second one `WORK` contains these columns:

```
ARB_REF, WORK_STREET - WORK_NUM, WORK_ZIP
```

I want to do the following: write a `select` query that search in work and see if the `WORK_STREET`, `WORK_ZIP` are duplicate together, then you should look at `WORK_NUM`. If it is the same then output value ' ok ', but if `WORK_NUM` is not the same, output 'not ok'

I wrote this SQL query:

```
select 
    A.ARB_REF, A.WORK_STREET, A.WORK_NUM, A.WORK_ZIP 
    case when B.B = 1 then 'OK' else 'not ok' end
from 
    work A
join 
    (select  
         WORK_STREET, WORK_ZIP count(distinct , A.WORK_NUM) B
     from 
         WORK
     group by 
         WORK_STREET, WORK_ZIP) B on B.WORK_STREET = A.WORK_STREET 
                                  and B.WORK_ZIP = A.WORK_ZIP
```

Now I want to join the table ORG with this result I want to check if every address belong to org if it belong I should create a new column `result` and set it to `yes` in it (RESULT) AND show the "name" column otherwise set no in 'RESULT'.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: `left outer join` to `org`. Then `case when org.arb_ref is not null then 'Yes' else 'No' end as result`

Comment: Left outer  join ORG on org.arb_ref=A.arb_ref and tom>.current date case when org.arb_refis not null then yes  else no as result ???? Is it correct

Comment: That's the right idea although the syntax isn't quite right and you refer to some previously unmentioned columns.

Comment: But i have another table that is Org-level that i should join with org table to get name of level from org  ex  left join org .....inner join org -level ol on  ol.org-ref=org.org-ref. I need it  so much to get the level name when the result is yes I should show which level name has this address  .and I can idea but syntax I cannot

Comment: See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

While you can accomplish your result by adding a left outer join to the query you've already started, it might be easiest to just use `count() over...`.

```
with org_data as (
    -- do the inner join before the left join later
    select * from org1 o1 inner join org2 o2 on o2.orgid = o1.orgid
)
select
     *,
     count(*) over (partition by WORK_STREET, WORKZIP) as cnt,
     case when o.ARB_REF is not null then 'Yes' else 'No' end as result
 from 
     WORK w left outer join org_data o on o.ARB_REF = w.ARB_REF
```